# Two port network and transformer?

Tags: transformer

How the circuit and equivalent circuit of a Transformer are derived? Does two port network help us in this regard to find the circuit and equivalent circuit of the transformer?

Secondly I need to know that what conditions should be fulfilled by two circuits so that they are considered to be equivalent. Of course there should be some set of rules to be fulfilled to declare the two circuits equivalent.

Comment: you answered the `Secondly` ... the circuits would be *equivalent*, if both circuits fulfill the set rules

Comment: The equivalent circuit of a transformer is a circuit model, which behaves under limited circumstances and for limited purposes somewhat like the real transformer.  Two circuits being equivalent must be defined by the requirements.  Equivalent under what circumstances and conditions? Board area? Power dissipation? Behavior at some terminal(s)?  The set of rules will vary depending on the purpose of the equivalent circuit.